# STRTOSET function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I have this mdx code into reporting service:

```
 WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS 
        [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
   MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
        [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
   MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS 
        [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL 
 SELECT 
     {
       [Measures].[ParameterCaption], 
       [Measures].[ParameterValue], 
       [Measures].[ParameterLevel]
     }  ON COLUMNS , 
     [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].Children ON ROWS 
 FROM 
   ( 
     SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimTiempoAnio) ) ON COLUMNS 
     FROM [BSC]
   );
```

I read into another questions we need to use `''` when we call STRTOSET, as you can see I have STRTOSET

```
( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@DimTiempoAnio) )
```

and I change it as

```
( SELECT ( STRTOSET('@DimTiempoAnio') )
```

but I get

[image]

Comment: Does `STRTOSET(@DimTiempoAnio, CONSTRAINED)` work?

Comment: No, I get: "the restrinctions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function where violated", that´s why I drop CONSTRAINED first @BishNaboB

Answer (score 0):

The constrained flag is there for a good reason - it will tell you if the string being fed into `STRTOSET` is valid or not. This message is telling you exactly that "the restrinctions imposed by the CONSTRAINED flag in the STRTOSET function where violated" .... so just dropping the flag is not the correct approach.

Can you simplify things and try just adding the following to your report to see if it throws an exception?

```
 SELECT 
    STRTOSET(@DimTiempoAnio) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM [BSC];
```

you need to ensure that the string `@DimTiempoAnio` is a string that can be converted into a valid `mdx` set - this would be valid example:

```
StrToSet ('[Geography].[State-Province].Members')
```

...so for the above as long as @DimTiempoAnio was equal to the string `[Geography].[State-Province].Members` then it'd be happy ... so the string you are feeding in as @DimTiempoAnio cannot be a valid mdx set expression